# Using Threads instead of Implicit Wait - Selecting row items on a dynamic grid

Tags: java, selenium, datagrid

please advise. I am familiar with Implicit Waits, yet this has not helped when trying to select a row entry from a grid in my Web Automation. A Main grid is loaded (with all line items 1-5 lets say), and a second grid is displayed also in the same screen. When each line item on Grid Main is selected, it loads the associated line items in the second grid. I have to click Line Item on Main Grid twice so that the sub-items are loaded. My challenge is when I use an Implicit Wait between the clicks, the script sometimes move to the next screen without clicking all the Line Items on Grid Main. I have decided to use Thread.sleep, I know this is bad practice but not sure whats the safest approach to prevent my script from ignoring the Line Items in Main Grid.
Please help.

```
    for (WebElement row : MainGrid) {
                while(ci<=gi){
                    try{
                        if (row.findElement(By.xpath(webElementID + "/tr[" + ci + "]/td[" + columnPos + "]/img")).isDisplayed()){
                            Thread.sleep(4000);                              
                            mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(webElementID + "/tr[" + ci + "]//td[" + columnPos + "]/img")).click();
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                            mydriver.findElement(By.xpath(webElementID + "/tr[" + ci + "]//td[" + columnPos + "]/img")).click();
                            Thread.sleep(4000);'
                            
                            String bundleValue = SubGridSelector.makeSelection(MainGrid, dataToUse, columnPos);
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                           
                        }
                    }catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException | NoSuchElementException | StaleElementReferenceException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }
                    ci=ci+1;
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                }
```

}

Comment: Why don't you go with Explicit wait ?

Comment: @NarendraR, thanks I was asked to avoid explicit waits by one of my peers. I have just not attempted to use that as they felt this is their standard. I will use and monitor then.

Comment: Using Explicit waits instead.